# Creating stackoverflow like tags

Tags: spacing, framed

I'm trying to create stackoverflow like tags. Currently I'm using an `\fbox{text}` to create the tags, which works, but not all boxes have the same height (it seems that letters like 'p' make a box take more height).

Is there a way to create something like `\fbox` but with a fixed height?

(They don't need to have a drop shadow or something like that. Just simple framed boxes)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should add a `\strut` so that all boxes have the same maximal height and depth, otherwise the framed box will depend on the height of the content. This means that an `a` gets a small box and `Xy` gets a higher and deeper one. With `\strut` a invisible rule is added which has the maximum height and depth of the current font size.

```
\newcommand*{\tag}[1]{\fbox{#1\strut}}
```

Fancier boxes can be created using the `fancybox` package.

Comment: @percusse: I also work on a [`tikzbox` package](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/9fd3d508a8b7/tikzbox.sty) which allows for easy usage of TikZ decorations around a text. It will be part of the `adjustbox` bundle.

Comment: I am aware of that work of yours and actually trying to get some affinity to it. What I wanted to say is that your last sentence was quite funny to me, but nevermind. Maybe I should refrain myself from putting such comments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

It might be simplest (although possibly overkill) to do this with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
  \node[draw, minimum height=4ex] (TAG) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\mytag{a tag}\mytag{Another Tag}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

It's overkill because the `\strut` solution is simpler.  It's not overkill if you want to make the boxes fancier than the `fancybox` package can give you.  A fancier version of the command would allow you to specify more parameters to the node command:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\mytag}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw, minimum height=4ex,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\mytag[fill=red!40, very thick,double, rounded corners]{a tag}

\mytag[ellipse,draw,blue]{Another Tag}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Just add a `\rule{0pt}{<min height>}` instead, or a `\strut` which is basically a special form of that.

Comment: Also you might want to keep the original baseline: `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
  \node[draw, minimum height=4ex] (TAG) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks. I agree about the `\strut` solution, which is clearly the simplest, so I've added some ideas about what else could be done with `tikz` in this context.  I've also added the baseline correction.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: A `\strut` has a depth, but `\rule` doesn't.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Usually you want a depth here. `\rule` can have a depth if you use the optional argument. `\strut` is equivalent to `\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}`. However, it is implemented differently.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you need any fancy stuff for the tag frame or whether you want to add some icons (like in the actual badges), but in case you do, you can use the [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{tag}{%
innerlinewidth=2pt,innerlinecolor=red,%
middlelinewidth=3pt,middlelinecolor=white,%
outerlinewidth=2pt,outerlinecolor=blue,%
}
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=4cm,style=tag]
this is my tag
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

This is what the output will be:

[image]

As a note I'd add that this is also based on TikZ (see the global option `framemethod=TikZ` in the preamble when you load the package) and also, the width of the box has to be set manually in the example, but I'm sure a method to automate this exists.

**EDIT:** I just couldn't leave it like that and had to fiddle with my code to produce an extended version that recreates the badges on our beloved site. `:)` The style is still created with `mdframed` and the medal is drawn with TikZ. The 'badge' takes two arguments: metal and badge text. Enjoy! `:)`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\global\mdfdefinestyle{tag}{%
innerlinewidth=1pt,innerlinecolor=black,%
middlelinewidth=2pt,middlelinecolor=white,%
outerlinewidth=1pt,outerlinecolor=black,%
backgroundcolor=black,fontcolor=white,%
}

\colorlet{gold}{yellow}
\colorlet{silver}{gray!20}
\colorlet{bronze}{orange}

\newcommand{\badge}[2]{%
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=5.5cm,style=tag]
\tikz{\draw[very thin,gray!75,fill=#1] (0,0) circle (1ex);\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangleside}{sqrt(3)}\draw[very thin,gray!75] (0,1ex) -- ++(240:\triangleside ex) -- +(0:\triangleside ex) -- cycle;} #2
\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\badge{gold}{This is my \TeX\ badge}
\badge{silver}{This is my \TeX\ badge}
\badge{bronze}{This is my \TeX\ badge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice output, congrats! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thanks! `:)` I really enjoyed tinkering around with this one and now I feel it paid off!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *drop shadow or something like that*, but you could use/misapply `keystroke`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{keystroke}

\begin{document}

\keystroke{aa}
\keystroke{AA}
\keystroke{p}

\end{document}
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: I prefer using XeLaTeX, `fontspec` and select [`Linux Biolinum Keyboard O`](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1) as a font for keyboard strokes.