# stackoverflow like resume based on res.cls

Tags: cv, resume

I have created a stackoverflow like CV, based on many snippets scattered here and some other sites (e.g. [tags](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35056/2266) and so on).

Right now, I have something that looks quite OK, although not as powerful as using the `moderncv` package.

However, I have still a few problems that bother me:

1. tags look really funny if I have a mix of lower and upper case names, see for example `gcc` and `GCC` below, or `MySQL` and `Python..`
2. because the `position` environment is very hard to control, I still do a lot of manual formating, . e.g.:

   `{{\bf {\large Scietific Programmer }}{\em \small Uni. British Columbia, Vancuver }, \hfill May, 2010 - Oct., 2010 
   }
   \\`

   I would like to create some new environment to define this formatting, in 
   such a way that the user can specify the order or the arguments and their format, for example, I want to define just one time how the environment should look like:

   `\Stelle[\Large][\normal,\italic][\normal][\normal]`

   the usage shoule be something like this:

   `\Stelle{Programmer}{CoolComany}{Chicago}{2012-Current}`

   As a side note, I think the German translation to "job position", "Stelle", is better than `position` , since the word `position` can be misunderstood as related to `location` and formating.

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4papper,overlapped,line]{res}
% \documentclass[a4papper,margin,line]{res}
\newsectionwidth{.7cm}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{SOrange}{rgb}{1,0.44,0.04}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{
{\scalefont{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}
\name{{\color{SOrange}Big Bird, M.Sc. }} 
\address{ \begin{tabular}{ll}
Seasamestr. 1            & {\it Land-line:}  +49 321 1231234 \\            
80337 Munich & {\it Mobile:}                \\         
 & {\it E-mail:}  bigbird@gmail.com\\       
 & {\it WWW:} bigbird.blogspot.com\\ 
 &\hspace{2.7em}             \\     
\end{tabular}}

\begin{resume}

\begin{changemargin}{-0.7cm}{-2.3cm}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{18pt}
\colorbox{blue!20}{
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}

\rmfamily
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{-0.54cm}{\scalefont{1.2}\textbf{\begin{Huge}\textquotedblleft\end{Huge}}}
\\
\vspace{-0.65cm}
\begin{small}
I have a dream: decent looking CV, for everyone! Good looking Resumes should be available, 
sould be documented and easy to use!
\textquotedblright
\end{small}\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}
}
\end{changemargin}

\vspace{0.50cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\section{\sc {\color{SOrange}\vspace{-0.60cm} \textbf{Professional Experience} }}
\vspace{0.20cm}
{{\bf {\large Systems Engineer }}{\em \small SomeCompany}, \hfill January, 2011 - Current  
}
\vspace{.13cm}
\\
Responsibilities include installation and configuration of Linux clusters and workstations, as well .....
% \hspace{-0.8cm}
\par
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{SAMBA}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Red Hat}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Windows}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{NFS}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Python}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Shell}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{MySQL}\hspace{-0.25cm}

{{\bf {\large Scietific Programmer }}{\em \small Uni. British Columbia, Vancuver }, \hfill May, 2010 - Oct., 2010 
}
\\
The main task was to implement ...The results were submitted as M.Sc thesis.
\par
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Fortran95}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Make}\hspace{-0.25cm}
% THIS LOOKS UGLY
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{gcc}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{GCC}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Python}\hspace{-0.25cm}

\section{\sc {\color{SOrange}\vspace{-0.60cm} \textbf{Education} }}
{\bf University of Life},  \hfill {\bf October, 2008 - October, 2011}\\
\vspace{-.7cm}

{\em M. Sc. Sociology }\\
Thesis Title:  ``How demographics won Romney'',  final GPA 1.3.
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output with funny looking tags:

[image: Stackoverflow like CV]

I would appreciate it, if someone helped me solving the issues with tags and the new `Stelle` environment.

#### update of results:

see the difference between both suggestions:
[image: strut vs vphantom]

`gcc without strut` is actually `with vphantom`.

### update of the results:

full source code based on the answers below and some extras can be found in my [github latex resume](https://github.com/oz123/latex_resume) repository. I hope you find use to it ...

Comment: It would really be helpful if you reduced your code down to what is needed to show the problem and removed everything else that is not related to this specific problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I removed some stuff, more cleaning needed? I also like your suggestions. Any clue how to the define the new environment?

Comment: Which environment are you trying to redefined? All you need to do is to add `\strut` or a `\vphantom{}` as in my answer below.

Comment: @PeterGrill, `position` as defined in the class. See point 2 of my question.

Comment: Sure, compose an example of the problem with just the `postion` environment, removing everything else -- then I can focus on the exact issue.

Comment: "I have a dream: decent looking CV, for everyone! Good looking Resumes should be available, sould be documented and easy to use!" and possibly typos free. Sorry couldn't resist :-)

Comment: @Guido, typos are not part of the template :-/ just my fault.

Comment: @Oz123 sure, just a (silly) joke.

Comment: In your definition of `\tagf` you draw two nodes, one on top of the other.  As far as I can make out the second overwrites the first completely meaning that the first needn't be there.  The `font=\tiny` is also later overridden by the options you provide when you actually invoke this command.  Do you really want it there?

Comment: @AndrewStacey, not really, this code was written while experiencing a Jet-lag, at 3.5 AM Berlin time ... so, it is quite raw, and made of lots of copy paste from tex.stackexchange.com as I said. Thanks for this comment too.

Comment: Resume looks good, but I thought your name was "Big Bird"? :-)  But, (_personal_ opinion here) I really dislike the way you have done the contact info. As a minimum the two phone numbers should aligned, as well as the email/web address. Also, "WWW"?? That should probably be "Web", or something else?

Comment: @PeterGrill, thanks for sharing your opinion. Actually, I am not even sure it is smart to put your blog or webadress, but since my inspiration was that website I put it. About the phones, you are right, that is ugly and needs correction.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I don't know if it is that smart to live so much info in the public, I deleted my personal contact, but there is enough info there people could find me if they really want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[As requested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82523/stackoverflow-like-resume-based-on-res-cls/82525#comment177004_82525) …*

But first, let me summarize some things:

- `\vphantom{y}` doesn't add vertical space like capital letters, in your all minuscule example you could add `\vphantom{Ay}` for example.

  The `\strut` is something similar by the way. It adds a zero-width vertical rule with a height (above the baseline) of `.7\baselineskip` and a depth (below the baseline) of `.3\baselineskip`.
  (You get the same effect with `\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}`.)

  Judging of the original example this was too much depth in my opinion, and as all other nodes had majuscule letter there was no need for more adjusting.
- The class option `a4papper` gives me—to no surprise—a warning as this option is none.
- Even though [`res`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res) is based on the `article` class it does not forward an option like `a4paper` so that I even get a warning than.
- … which is the reason for using `[a4paper]{article}` in my examples (but you can, of course, use any class you want)
- Your `\hspace{-.25cm}` is unneeded if you add a `%` at the end of the lines containing your tag. (→ [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines))
  *(In my comment I was wrong: The additional horizontal space doesn't come from `outer sep` but from the space that is inserted.)*
- `\fontsize{0.1}{.1}` doesn't work, it even gives a warning:

  ```
  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <0.1> not available 
                                                    size <5> substituted on input line 48.
  ```
- `font=\tiny` doesn't get used, as it gets overwritten, too.
- All the while you're using `\scalefont{0.8}` anyway. Let's just use that.
- Don't use `\it`. (→ [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/16595))

Now, before we play with all the `\vphantom`s, `\rule`s and `\strut`s they are, we just make use of TikZ' own styles, namely:

- `text height` and
- `text depth`.

We get the most appealing output (in my eyes) when we don't use a depth (ignoring all descenders in letters like `y` and `g`) and set the height to the one of a majuscule letter. When the above mentioned TikZ styles are used the actual heights and depths of the node text are ignored.

We could mimic this output using `\vphantom{A}\smash{#2}` as the node text (`#2` being the actual text), or, with the help of [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s extension of `\smash`, `\smash[b]{#2}` (`b` stands for bottom, i.e. only the bottom part is smashed).

TikZ' default settings of `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` of `.3333em` make sure that the lines have a little padding to the text. (These settings can be changed, too, of course, to get yet another output.)

### To cut a long story short

#### Code

```
\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{{%
    \scalefont{0.8}%
    \sbox0{A}%
    \tikz[baseline={(TAG.base)}]{
    \node[draw=blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, text height=\ht0, text depth=0pt, #1] (TAG) {#2};
    }%
}}
```

#### Output

[image]

### Depths? Heights? What the …?

(`\strut` has problems inside a TikZ-node inside `tabular` so I removed it from the last column.)

#### Table

[image]

#### Closer

[image]

## Full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}% to mimic res' output
\usepackage{tikz}   % loads xcolor by default
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amsmath}% only for the extended version of \smash
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{{%
    \scalefont{0.8}%
    \sbox0{A}%
    \tikz[baseline={(TAG.base)}]{
    \node[draw=blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, text height=\ht0, text depth=0pt, #1] (TAG) {#2};
    }%
}}
\begin{document}
Responsibilities include installation and configuration of Linux clusters and workstations
\tagf{SAMBA}%
\tagf{Red Hat}%
\tagf{Windows}%
\tagf{NFS}%
\tagf{Python}%
\tagf{Shell}%
\tagf{MySQL} %
Responsibilities include installation and configuration of Linux clusters and workstations
\par
Responsibilities include installation and configuration of Linux clusters and workstations
\tagf{Fortran95}%
\tagf{Make}%
\tagf{gcc}%
\tagf{GCC}%
\tagf{Python}
Responsibilities include installation and configuration of Linux clusters and workstations
\par

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The following code should not be used inside your resumee! %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\boxme}[2][black]{{%
    \fboxrule=.4pt%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    {\color{#1}\fbox{\color{black}#2}}%
}}
\newcommand{\showmeheightanddepth}[2][]{%
    \global\sbox0{#2}%
    \rlap{\kern-.4em\rule[-.1pt]{\wd0+.8em}{.2pt}}% baseline
    \boxme{#2}#1 
    & \the\ht0
    & \the\dp0
    & \the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
    & \ifx#2\strut\else\let\boxme\dontboxmeinsideTikZ%
        \tagf[text height=, text depth=]{#2}\fi
}
\newcommand{\dontboxmeinsideTikZ}[2][black]{%
    #2%
}
\edef\baselineskipinnormaltext{\the\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrc}
 boxed & height & depth & totalheight & Ti\emph{k}Z \\\hline
\showmeheightanddepth{ace}\\
\showmeheightanddepth{ABC}\\
\showmeheightanddepth{gy}\\
\showmeheightanddepth{Age}\\
\showmeheightanddepth{\vphantom{A}\smash{\boxme[green]{Age}}}\\
\showmeheightanddepth{\smash[b]{\boxme[green]{Age}}}\\ % needs \usepackage{amsmath}
\showmeheightanddepth[ (\texttt{strut})]{\strut}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are my `\LaTeX` god! Thanks a bunch for sharing so much knowledge.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a `\strut` so that each node is the same height:

[image]

As per **Qrrbrbirlbel's** suggestion, using `\vphantom{y}` produces slightly tighter output:

```
\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\vphantom{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
  \node[draw, minimum height=1ex] (TAG) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
    \node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
    \node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\strut};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{SAMBA}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Red Hat}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Windows}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{NFS}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Python}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Shell}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{MySQL}\hspace{-0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

---

You can also greatly simply your code if you use `\tikzset` to define styles, and use a `\foreach` loop for repetitive tasks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\vphantom{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzset{My Tag Style/.style={blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, , font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {SAMBA, Red Hat, Windows, NFS, Python, Shell, MySQL} {%
    \tagf[My Tag Style]{\x}\hspace{-0.25cm}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative: `\vphantom{y}` (not so much depth, looks a bit nicer IMO)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yep, added that option.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I just added both to my document. `\strut` is better, because there is not difference between `gcc` and `GCC`. See my attached images.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I guess the best solution really would be to use `\vphantom{}` and list the letters with the greatest height and depth in there. That way you would have exactly the right size. Just have to be careful that if the letters are changes, that the `\vphantom{}` is adjusted. Of course you could automate this as well, but probably not worth the effort since this is not something you are using repeatedly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, you really ought to post an answer instead of so many comments. Would be nice if you did actually! Would not harm any way, and for sure you will get my upvote!

Comment: @Oz123 As you wish … and I corrected some stuff I wrote in my comments. They are mostly obsolete now …