# tikz bug when creating stackoverflow tags?

Tags: tikz-pgf, resume

I am still working on my  template for [stackexchange like resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82523/2266), and I noticed that if I issue the `\LaTeX` macro inside a Tikz box, the `A` gets trimmed.

The header of my document contains:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{
{
\scalefont{0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
```

I want to do the following:

```
 \tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Makefile}\hspace{-0.25cm}
 \tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{GCC}\hspace{-0.25cm}
 \tagf[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{Python}\hspace{-0.25cm}
 \LaTeX
 \tagfb[blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}]{\LaTeX}\hspace{-0.25cm}
```

The odd result is:

[image: Latex trimmed]

### Update

I compiled a complete snippet, which works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{times} %if use this, the macro is broken.
%\usepackage{times} %commenting this lines out works 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\tagf}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\vphantom{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tagfb}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(TAG.base)}]
\node[draw,#1] (TAG) {#2};
\node[font=\tiny,draw,#1] (TAG) {#2\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzset{My Tag Style/.style={blue!80, fill=blue!20,  rounded corners, , font=\fontsize{0.1}{.1}}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {SAMBA, Red Hat, Windows, NFS, Python, Shell, \LaTeX, MySQL} {%
    \tagf[My Tag Style]{\x}
}

\foreach \x in {SAMBA, Red Hat, Windows, NFS, Python, Shell, \LaTeX, MySQL} {%
    \tagfb[My Tag Style]{\x}
}
\end{document}
```

Original question is: is this a bug? If not, how can I fix this behavior?

**Updated question:**
I think this is not a 100% bug, and if so, not sure that it is in `Tikz`, maybe in the `times` package. So, how can I cause just the tags to have the correct font, and the rest of document have the font `times`?

[image]

Comment: Please submit the compilable complete code rather than code snippets.

Comment: I think is something related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82523/stackoverflow-like-resume-based-on-res-cls, but anyway having here a [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) will help in any case. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with TikZ and everything to do with a rather odd command in your tag style: `\fontsize{0.1}{.1}`.  This says "Next time you select a font, make it of size `.1pt`." (and something else with the second `.1` - I think that's related to line size).  Inside the `\LaTeX` macro is a `\selectfont` command (for the `A`) and that picks up the declared font size.  However, as *you* haven't invoked the `\selectfont` yourself then the `L TEX` are still set in the current font size, whence visible.  The reason that this occurs with `times` and not without it is that `times` is a scalable font but computer modern (the default) bottoms out at around 8pt so when `times` is asked "Set the font size to .1pt" then it does so but when computer modern is asked it then it says, "Nah, I'm using 8pt" instead.

The following code demonstrates the problem (note that I'm using `pgffor` just for the loop, there's no TikZ involved here).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82601/86}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{times} %<-- comment out or not to see the difference

\begin{document}

\foreach \fnt in {1,2,...,16} {

  \fnt:\fontsize{\fnt}{\fnt}\selectfont\LaTeX
}

\end{document}
```

Result with times:

[image: scaled font with times]

Result with CM:

[image: computer modern version]

Comment: thanks man! I was actually wondering about those font size. That was just a legacy from my (lame) tries to control the box size before I started using `scalefnt`.